# Firebase plugin error mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have this code on my gradle file but I have an error which says

"mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes"

I made this project using the assistant of android studio

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: check gradle tree dependency to check which library create conflicts

Comment: use firebase dependencies of same version, for example 16.0.1 for all of them

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1' to '16.0.6'. It's the most up-to-date version.